# i want to write a console app that get int value from user and put them in a array

Tags: c#

i want to write a console app that get int value from user and put them in a array and show sum of the numbers and min and max of them and then print them in the console in order

i write until this point of project but have some bugs...

```
      Console.WriteLine("\n   Please Enter the Number of your Numbers: \n");
      int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


      Console.WriteLine("   Please Enter Your Numbers:");


      int[] myArray = new int[k];
      int sum = 0;

      
      //INPUT
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
      {
          myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("   Number [" + (i+1) + "]: " + myArray[i] + "     and Next:");
         }
      
      
      //DELETE DUPLICATE ELEMENTS
      int[] newArray = myArray.Distinct().ToArray();


      //SORT
      Array.Sort(newArray);
      Console.WriteLine("\n   Your Sorted Numbers Without Duplicated ones: ");
      foreach (int i in newArray)
      {
          Console.Write("   | " + i);
         }
         
      Console.Write(" |");
```

Comment: "but have some bugs..." Describe those bugs. Explain what is and isn't working. Give some example input, expected output, and actual output. You should also consider a [mcve].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i think you are trying to make a program like this:

```
int i,n;
int[] a = new int[100];
Console.WriteLine("element numbers :");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("please entre your numbers : ", n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{Console.WriteLine($"element i");
a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());}
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{sum += a[i];}
Console.WriteLine("sum is : {0}", sum);
int max = a[0];
int min = a[0];
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{if (a[i] > max)
{max = a[i];}
if (a[i] < min)
{min = a[i];}}
Console.WriteLine("max is : " + max);
Console.WriteLine("min is : " + min);
Console.WriteLine("element numbers are: ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{Console.WriteLine(a[i]);}
```

Comment: Some explanation how this solves the question, please.